# HELP TCP Server in C cannot save in MYSQL !

Tags: mysql, c

I'm developing a TCP Server in C language that can save data to mysql. 
The problem is "buf" cannot be save/insert into mysql. But "name" can be save/insert into mysql.  Do u know what is the problem is? and how to fix that? I'm very glad if u can help me. 
below is the code.

to compile :
gcc -o tcpecho $(mysql_config --cflags) tcpecho.c $(mysql_config --libs)

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd describe exactly what happens when you run the code.  What data are you expecting to see?  What happens when you try to insert it into the database?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data from the first call to `recv` is discarded without being inserted into the database.  Also, you're passing the results of the later `recv` calls to `sprintf` without null-terminating them at the correct position for the number of bytes read
in that call.